# C program compilation woes

Tags: c

When this code is compiled the resulting calculations for the Total and Average sections are displaying varying results other than shown below. I have displayed below in this question what the results should look like. However if you click on the link provided to IDEone you can see the results I am getting from my code. My question is what needs to change in my code to achieve the correct outcome?

---

```
Name            Clock#   Wage   Hours     OT     Gross
---------------------------------------------------------
Connie Cobol    098401   10.60   51.0    11.0    598.90
Mary Apl        526488    9.75   42.5     2.5    426.56
Frank Fortran   765349   10.50   37.0     0.0    388.50
Jeff Ada        034645   12.25   45.0     5.0    581.88
Anton Pascal    127615   10.00   40.0     0.0    400.00
---------------------------------------------------------

Total:                          215.5    18.5    2395.84
Average:                         43.1     3.7    479.168
```

[Link to Ideone Here](http://ideone.com/uooCeT)

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* Define Constants */
#define NUM_EMPL 5
#define OVERTIME_RATE 1.5f
#define STD_WORK_WEEK 40.0f

struct employee
{
char first_name[20];
char last_name[20];
long clock_number;
float wage_rate;
float hours;
float OT;
float gross;
float total_hours;
float avg_hours;
float total_OT;
float avg_OT;
float total_gross;
float avg_gross;
};

/* define prototypes here for each function except main */
void Get_Input (struct employee [NUM_EMPL]);
void Gross_pay_calc (struct employee [NUM_EMPL]);
void Output_results_screen (struct employee [NUM_EMPL]);
void Total_and_Avg (struct employee [NUM_EMPL]);

/*************************************************************************/
/* Function: Output_results_screen */
/* */
/* Purpose: Outputs to screen in a table format the following */
/* information about an employee: Clock, Wage, */
/* Hours, Overtime, and Gross Pay. */
/* */
/* Parameters: employeeData - an array of structures containing */
/* employee information */
/* */
/* Returns: Nothing (void) */
/* */
/************************************************************************/

void Output_results_screen (struct employee employeeData[NUM_EMPL])
{
int idx; /* loop index */

        printf ("\n\tGeorge Smith, C Programming, Fifth Homework Assignment\n\n");
        printf ("\t----------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf ("\tName            Clock#  Wage    Hours    OT      Gross\n");
        printf ("\t----------------------------------------------------------\n");

/* printf information about each employee */
for (idx = 0; idx < NUM_EMPL ; ++idx)
{
        printf("\t%s %s \t%06li \t%5.2f \t%4.1f \t%4.1f \t%6.2f \n",employeeData[idx].first_name, employeeData[idx].last_name, employeeData[idx].clock_number, employeeData[idx].wage_rate, employeeData[idx].hours,employeeData[idx].OT, employeeData[idx].gross);
} /* for */
        printf ("\t----------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf ("Total: \t\t\t\t\t%5.1f \t%5.1f \t%5.2f\n",employeeData[idx].total_hours, employeeData[idx].total_OT, employeeData[idx].total_gross);
        printf ("Average: \t\t\t\t%5.1f \t%5.1f \t%5.3f", employeeData[idx].avg_hours, employeeData[idx].avg_OT, employeeData[idx].avg_gross);
} /* Output_results_screen */

/*function for user input*/
void Get_Input (struct employee employeeData[NUM_EMPL])
{
     int idx; /* loop index */

     /* printf information about each employee */
     for (idx = 0; idx < NUM_EMPL ; ++idx)
     {
         printf("\nEnter hours worked for employee %06li : ",employeeData[idx].clock_number);
         scanf("%f",&employeeData[idx].hours);
     }
}
/*function to calculate overtime and gross pay*/
void Gross_pay_calc (struct employee employeeData[NUM_EMPL])
{
     int idx; /* loop index */

     /* printf information about each employee */
     for (idx = 0; idx < NUM_EMPL ; ++idx)
     {
         if (employeeData[idx].hours <= STD_WORK_WEEK)
         {
            employeeData[idx].OT = 0.0;
            employeeData[idx].gross = employeeData[idx].wage_rate * employeeData[idx].hours;
         }

          else if (employeeData[idx].hours > STD_WORK_WEEK)
          {
            employeeData[idx].OT = employeeData[idx].hours - STD_WORK_WEEK;
            employeeData[idx].gross = (STD_WORK_WEEK * employeeData[idx].wage_rate) + (employeeData[idx].OT * (OVERTIME_RATE * employeeData[idx].wage_rate));
          }

     }
}

/*function to calculate overtime and gross pay*/
void Total_and_Avg (struct employee employeeData [NUM_EMPL])
{
int idx; /* loop index */
float total_hours=0;
float avg_hours;
float total_OT=0;
float avg_OT;
float total_gross=0;
float avg_gross;
/* printf information about each employee */
     for (idx = 0; idx < NUM_EMPL ; ++idx)
{
    total_hours+= employeeData[idx].hours;
    avg_hours= total_hours/employeeData[idx].hours;
    total_OT+= employeeData[idx].OT;
    avg_OT= total_OT/employeeData[idx].OT;
    total_gross+= employeeData[idx].gross;
    avg_gross= total_gross/employeeData[idx].gross;
}
}

int main()
{
/* Variable Declaration and initialization */
struct employee employeeData[NUM_EMPL] = {
{"Connie", "Cobol", 98401, 10.60},
{"Mary", "Apl", 526488, 9.75},
{"Frank", "Fortran", 765349, 10.50},
{"Jeff", "Ada", 34645, 12.25},
{"Anton", "Pascal", 127615, 8.35}
};

/* Call various functions needed to reading, calculating, and printing as needed */
Get_Input(employeeData);
Gross_pay_calc(employeeData);
/* Function call to output results to the screen in table format. */
Output_results_screen (employeeData);
Total_and_Avg (employeeData);
return(0); /* success */

}; /* main */
```

Comment: 1) Your title is inaccurate, 2) you should post code, not  link to it, 3) most important of all, you should **start with something small and simple,** and not just write lots of code and be surprised when it doesn't work.

Comment: Also this is not a "compilation woe", it's a run-time woe. :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! @Beta's comments are spot-on; you should simplify this and work with a smaller chunk of code. Stack Overflow works best when you present a discrete problem, not a wall of code that isn't working the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have:

```
float total_hours;
float avg_hours;
float total_OT;
float avg_OT;
float total_gross;
float avg_gross;
```

inside `struct employee` ?

If I understand your design, then these are numbers that you only want one copy of each, and you update that single set of numbers based on every employee.

The code in the `Total_And_Avg` function makes no sense at all, because you are just updating local variables which you never return (so they are lost).

Your garbage output comes from the line:

```
printf ("Total: \t\t\t\t\t%5.1f \t%5.1f \t%5.2f\n",
  employeeData[idx].total_hours, [...]
```

because at this point `idx` has gone off the end of the loop, so you are reading from invalid memory.

Also, you call `Output_results_screen` before you call `Total_and_Avg` so even if you did that right you would still get garbage.

You need a major design re-think.  I'd start by removing those bogus variables from `struct employee`. Then you will have to do something with the variables in `Total_and_Avg`.  It would be easiest to just output them at the end of that function, moving the last 3 lines of `Output_results_screen` into `Total_and_Avg`.

If you want to use a different function to calculate totals than to display totals, you will have to ensure those variables are visible in both.  One way to do that would be to put those variables into another `struct`, which you create in `main()` and pass by reference to both `Total_and_Avg` and `Output_results_screen`.

Finally, your calculations in the `Total_and_Avg` function are very wrong.  Once you fix your program structure so that you can properly display these results, then you can try again to get them right. Think about how you'd work out the totals and averages on paper, and then try to make your code reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

take this: it shows right  results, your code is not wrong you are just mis-using stuff

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* Define Constants */
#define NUM_EMPL 5
#define OVERTIME_RATE 1.5f
#define STD_WORK_WEEK 40.0f

struct employee
{
char first_name[20];
char last_name[20];
long clock_number;
float wage_rate;
float hours;
float OT;
float gross;
//float total_hours;
//float avg_hours;
//float total_OT;
//float avg_OT;
//float total_gross;
//float avg_gross;
};

struct total
{
float total_hours;
float avg_hours;
float total_OT;
float avg_OT;
float total_gross;
float avg_gross;
}total_calc;

/* define prototypes here for each function except main */
void Get_Input (struct employee [NUM_EMPL]);
void Gross_pay_calc (struct employee [NUM_EMPL]);
void Output_results_screen (struct employee [NUM_EMPL]);
void Total_and_Avg (struct employee [NUM_EMPL]);

/*************************************************************************/
/* Function: Output_results_screen */
/* */
/* Purpose: Outputs to screen in a table format the following */
/* information about an employee: Clock, Wage, */
/* Hours, Overtime, and Gross Pay. */
/* */
/* Parameters: employeeData - an array of structures containing */
/* employee information */
/* */
/* Returns: Nothing (void) */
/* */
/************************************************************************/

void Output_results_screen (struct employee employeeData[NUM_EMPL])
{
int idx; /* loop index */

        //printf ("\n\tGeorge Smith, C Programming, Fifth Homework Assignment\n\n");
        printf ("\n\t----------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf ("\tName            Clock#  Wage    Hours    OT      Gross\n");
        printf ("\t----------------------------------------------------------\n");

/* printf information about each employee */
for (idx = 0; idx < NUM_EMPL ; ++idx)
{
        printf("\t%s %s \t%06li \t%5.2f \t%4.1f \t%4.1f \t%6.2f \n",employeeData[idx].first_name, employeeData[idx].last_name, employeeData[idx].clock_number, employeeData[idx].wage_rate, employeeData[idx].hours,employeeData[idx].OT, employeeData[idx].gross);
} /* for */
        printf ("\t----------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf ("Total: \t\t\t\t\t%5.1f \t%5.1f \t%5.2f\n",total_calc.total_hours, total_calc.total_OT, total_calc.total_gross);
        printf ("Average: \t\t\t\t%5.1f \t%5.1f \t%5.3f", total_calc.avg_hours, total_calc.avg_OT, total_calc.avg_gross);
} /* Output_results_screen */

/*function for user input*/
void Get_Input (struct employee employeeData[NUM_EMPL])
{
     int idx; /* loop index */

     /* printf information about each employee */
     for (idx = 0; idx < NUM_EMPL ; ++idx)
     {
         printf("\nEnter hours worked for employee %06li : ",employeeData[idx].clock_number);
         scanf("%f",&employeeData[idx].hours);
     }
}
/*function to calculate overtime and gross pay*/
void Gross_pay_calc (struct employee employeeData[NUM_EMPL])
{
     int idx; /* loop index */

     /* printf information about each employee */
     for (idx = 0; idx < NUM_EMPL ; ++idx)
     {
         if (employeeData[idx].hours <= STD_WORK_WEEK)
         {
            employeeData[idx].OT = 0.0;
            employeeData[idx].gross = employeeData[idx].wage_rate * employeeData[idx].hours;
         }

          else if (employeeData[idx].hours > STD_WORK_WEEK)
          {
            employeeData[idx].OT = employeeData[idx].hours - STD_WORK_WEEK;
            employeeData[idx].gross = (STD_WORK_WEEK * employeeData[idx].wage_rate) + (employeeData[idx].OT * (OVERTIME_RATE * employeeData[idx].wage_rate));
          }

     }
}

/*function to calculate overtime and gross pay*/
void Total_and_Avg (struct employee employeeData [NUM_EMPL])
{
int idx; /* loop index */
float total_hours=0;
float avg_hours;
float total_OT=0;
float avg_OT;
float total_gross=0;
float avg_gross;
/* printf information about each employee */
     for (idx = 0; idx < NUM_EMPL ; ++idx)
{
    total_hours+= employeeData[idx].hours;

    //avg_hours= total_hours/employeeData[idx].hours;

    total_OT+= employeeData[idx].OT;

    //avg_OT= total_OT/employeeData[idx].OT;

    total_gross+= employeeData[idx].gross;

    //avg_gross= total_gross/employeeData[idx].gross;

}
avg_hours = total_hours/NUM_EMPL;
avg_OT = total_OT/NUM_EMPL;
avg_gross = total_gross/NUM_EMPL;

total_calc.total_hours = total_hours;
total_calc.avg_hours = total_hours/NUM_EMPL;
total_calc.total_OT = total_OT;
total_calc.avg_OT = total_OT/NUM_EMPL;
total_calc.total_gross = total_gross;
total_calc.avg_gross = total_gross/NUM_EMPL;
}

int main()
{
/* Variable Declaration and initialization */
struct employee employeeData[NUM_EMPL] = {
{"Connie", "Cobol", 98401, 10.60},
{"Mary", "Apl", 526488, 9.75},
{"Frank", "Fortran", 765349, 10.50},
{"Jeff", "Ada", 34645, 12.25},
{"Anton", "Pascal", 127615, 10.0} // 8.35
};
//total total_calc;

/* Call various functions needed to reading, calculating, and printing as needed */
Get_Input(employeeData);
Gross_pay_calc(employeeData);
/* Function call to output results to the screen in table format. */
Total_and_Avg (employeeData);
Output_results_screen (employeeData);

return(0); /* success */

}; /* main */
```